# Tiny Language compiler using python and regex

Tags: python, regex, compiler-construction

Hello stack overflow users
I hope you having a good
so I'm doing this tiny language compiler for my homework
tried using regex
but the output is so weird
First of all, I get an Identifier called 't' which is not used in my input
And it doesn't separate Identifier 'x' from the semicolon
thanks in advance for your help

Here is my input

```
read x;   {input an integer }
     if  0 < x   then     {  don’t compute if x <= 0 }
        fact  := 1;
        repeat 
           fact  := fact *  x;
            x  := x  -  1 
        until  x  =  0;
        write  fact   {  output  factorial of x }
     end
```

And that's my code using regex

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed May 13 04:11:06 2020

@author: PC
"""

class OwnCompiler (object):
    def __init__ (self,file):
        import re
        self.file=open(file,"r").readlines()
        self.symbols = {
                "+":"PLUS_OP",
                "-":"MINUS_OP",
                "*":"MUL_OP",
                "/":"DIV_OP",
                "=":"EQUAL_OP",
                "<":"LESS_OP",
                ">":"GREATER_OP",
                "(":"LEFT_PARENTHESIS",
                ")":"RIGHT_PARENTHESIS",
                ":=":"ASSIGN",
                ";":"SEMICOLON",
                }
        self.commentPattern = re.compile(r".*({\n*\s*.*\s*})")
        self.reservePattern = re.compile(r"\s*(read|write|if|then|else|end|repeat|until)+\s*(.*)(then)*")
        self.symbolPattern = re.compile(r".*(\+|\*|-|/|=|<|>|\(|\)|;)")
        self.identifierSymbol = re.compile(r".*(\w+)\s+(:=)\s+(.*)")

    def compileOutput(self):
        self.fileWrite=open("output.txt","w")
        self.fileWrite.write("Type        Token\n==================\n")
        for i in self.file :
            print(i)
            self.getComment(i)
            self.getReserveWord(i)
            self.getIdentify(i)
        self.fileWrite.close()#end
    def getComment(self,text):
        try:
            self.fileWrite.write("COMMENT        "+self.commentPattern.match(text).group(1)+"\n")
        except:
            print("NO_COMMENT")
    def getReserveWord(self,text):
        self.Compiled = self.reservePattern.match(text)
        try:
            self.fileWrite.write("RESERVE_WORD        "+self.Compiled.group(1)+"\n")
            self.getSymbols(self.Compiled.group(2))
            try:
                self.fileWrite.write("RESERVE_WORD        "+self.Compiled.group(3)+"\n")
            except:
                print("NO_RESERVE_WORD2")
        except:
            print("NO_RESERVE_WORD")
    def getSymbols(self,text):
        self.Compiled= self.symbolPattern.match(text)
        self.GOT_TOKEN= self.getTokensSymbols(self.Compiled.group())
        try:
            self.fileWrite.write(self.GOT_TOKEN+"        "+self.Compiled.group()+"\n")
        except:
            print("NO_SYMBOLS")
    def getIdentify(self,text):
        self.Compiled = self.identifierSymbol.match(text)
        try:
            self.fileWrite.write("IDENTIFIER        "+self.Compiled.group(1)+"\n")
            self.getSymbols(text)
            for i in self.Compiled.group(3):
                if i ==" " :
                    continue
                if self.isNumber(i):
                    self.fileWrite.write("NUMBER        ")
                else:
                    self.fileWrite.write("WORD        ")
                self.fileWrite.write(self.Compiled.group(3)+"\n")
        except:
            print("NO_IDENTIFIRES")
    def getTokensSymbols(self,symbol):
        try: 
            return self.symbols[symbol]
        except:
            print("NOT_DEFINED_IN_SYMBOL_DICT")
            return "UNKNOWN"

    def isNumber(self,text):
         try:
             int(text)
             return True
         except:
             return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = OwnCompiler("input.txt")
    instance.compileOutput()
```

And here is my output

```
Type        Token
==================
COMMENT        { Sample program in TINY language – computes factorial }
COMMENT        {input an integer }
RESERVE_WORD        read
UNKNOWN        x;
COMMENT        {  don’t compute if x <= 0 }
RESERVE_WORD        if
UNKNOWN        0 < x   then     {  don’t compute if x <=
IDENTIFIER        t
UNKNOWN                fact  := 1;
RESERVE_WORD        repeat
IDENTIFIER        t
UNKNOWN                   fact  := fact *  x;
IDENTIFIER        x
UNKNOWN                    x  := x  -
RESERVE_WORD        until
UNKNOWN        x  =  0;
COMMENT        {  output  factorial of x }
RESERVE_WORD        write
RESERVE_WORD        end
```

Comment: The code currently given doesn't constitute a [mcve] -- someone can't run it themselves to reproduce a problem or test a fix. BTW, usually I'd use one of the many available parser generators. And typically, `.*` shouldn't be used anywhere in a compiler -- remember, it's greedy; so in `if(.*)end`, if you have `if foo; then bar; end; something-else; if qux; then meh; end`, the first `if` will go all the way to the end of your program instead of stopping at the `end` instance it matches.

Comment: made an update for the code part, sorry it doesn't match minimal reproducible example, cause I really don't know what's wrong with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to parse a language you need a 'lexer' that will return *individual tokens* ignoring whitespace and comments. Along these lines, just as an example:

```
import re, collections

class Lexer(object):

    WHITESPACE = r'(?P<WHITESPACE>\s+)'
    COMMENT = r'(?P<COMMENT>{[^}]*})'
    READ = r'(?P<READ>\bread\b)'
    WRITE = r'(?P<WRITE>\bwrite\b)'
    IF = r'(?P<IF>\bif\b)'
    THEN = r'(?P<THEN>\bthen\b)'
    ELSE = r'(?P<ELSE>\belse\b)'
    END = r'(?P<END>\bend\b)'
    REPEAT = r'(?P<REPEAT>\brepeat\b)'
    UNTIL = r'(?P<UNTIL>\buntil\b)'
    OPERATOR = r'(?P<OPERATOR>(?:[+*/=<>-]|:=))'
    LPAREN = r'(?P<LPAREN>\()'
    RPAREN = r'(?P<RPAREN>\))'
    IDENTIFIER = r'(?P<IDENTIFIER>[a-z]+)'
    INTEGER = r'(?P<INTEGER>\d+)'
    SEMICOLON = r'(?P<SEMICOLON>;)'

    regex = re.compile('|'.join([
        WHITESPACE,
        COMMENT,
        READ,
        WRITE,
        IF,
        THEN,
        ELSE,
        END,
        REPEAT,
        UNTIL,
        OPERATOR,
        LPAREN,
        RPAREN,
        IDENTIFIER,
        INTEGER,
        SEMICOLON
        ]))

    def __init__ (self, file):

        def generate_tokens(text):
            Token = collections.namedtuple('Token', ['type','value'])
            scanner = Lexer.regex.finditer(text)
            last_end = 0
            for m in scanner:
                start = m.start()
                end = m.end()
                if start != last_end:
                    # skipped over text to find the next token implies that there was unrecognizable text or an "error token"
                    text = self.text[last_end:start]
                    token = Token('ERROR', text)
                    yield token
                last_end = end
                token = Token(m.lastgroup, m.group())
                if token.type != 'WHITESPACE' and token.type != 'COMMENT':
                    yield token
            yield Token('EOF', '<end-of-file>')


        with open(file, "r") as f:
            text = f.read()
            self._token_generator = generate_tokens(text)

    def next_token(self):
        # if you call this past the "EOF" token you will get a StopIteration exception
        return self._token_generator.__next__()


lexer = Lexer('input.txt')
while True:
    token = lexer.next_token()
    print(token)
    if token.type == 'EOF':
        break
```

Prints:

```
Token(type='READ', value='read')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='x')
Token(type='SEMICOLON', value=';')
Token(type='IF', value='if')
Token(type='INTEGER', value='0')
Token(type='OPERATOR', value='<')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='x')
Token(type='THEN', value='then')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='fact')
Token(type='OPERATOR', value=':=')
Token(type='INTEGER', value='1')
Token(type='SEMICOLON', value=';')
Token(type='REPEAT', value='repeat')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='fact')
Token(type='OPERATOR', value=':=')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='fact')
Token(type='OPERATOR', value='*')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='x')
Token(type='SEMICOLON', value=';')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='x')
Token(type='OPERATOR', value=':=')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='x')
Token(type='OPERATOR', value='-')
Token(type='INTEGER', value='1')
Token(type='UNTIL', value='until')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='x')
Token(type='OPERATOR', value='=')
Token(type='INTEGER', value='0')
Token(type='SEMICOLON', value=';')
Token(type='WRITE', value='write')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='fact')
Token(type='END', value='end')
Token(type='EOF', value='<end-of-file>')
```